# Security handshake failed when trying to send response in express route

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express

I'm building a twitter sentiment reader and I am running into issues when I try and send a response back to angular. Everything worked fine before I added `res.send()` and it logged the sentiment.

Now that I added the res.send() function, it errors out sending the data back to angular. Angular has it as an error 500 and my node console has the error saying POST /postUsername Security Handshake Failed: **some library stuff** Description: End of TCP Stream".

Express Route

```
router.post("/postUsername", function(req, res){
  console.log(req.body.userName);
  var client = new Twitter({
    consumer_key: '',
    consumer_secret: '',
    access_token_key: '',
    access_token_secret: ''
  });// client
  client.get('statuses/user_timeline', {screen_name: req.body.userName, count:20}, function(error, tweets, response) {
    tweet = analyzeIt.seperateData(tweets);
    var document = language.document(tweet);
    if (!error) {
      var parsedScore;
      var parsedMagnitude;
      var finalScore;
      var options = {
        verbose: true
      }; // options
      document.detectSentiment(options, function(err, score) {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
        } //if err
          parsedScore = score.score;
          parsedMagnitude = score.magnitude;
          finalScore = analyzeIt.finalScore(parsedScore, parsedMagnitude);
          console.log(finalScore);
        });//detect sentiment
      }//if not error
    });//client get statuses
    res.send(finalScore);
  });//router post
```

Angular Controller

```
app.controller('myController', function($scope, $http){

  $scope.sendData = function() {
    var data = { userName: $scope.userName };
    console.log($scope.userName);
    $http.post('/postUsername', data)
    .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
      $scope.PostDataResponse = data;
    })
    .error(function (data, status, header, config) {
      $scope.PostDataResponse = "Data: " + status;
    });
  };
});
```

The expected output would be something like "This user trends positive."

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: It looks like you are sending your response before the `client.get` has had a chance to respond. Shouldn't `res.send(finalScore)` be called inside of the `client.get` callback? The same thing goes for `detectSentiment`. You are trying to access `finalScore` outside of the callback

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see a few problems. First is that you are responding immediately, without waiting for the twitter request to complete.

```
// Call order: #1
client.get(..., function(error, tweets, response) { 
  // Call order: #3
  // anything in here no longer matters
});
// Call order: #2
res.send(finalScore) //because this executes before the code in the callback above
```

So essentially when the call is made from angular, express immediately sends back the value of `finalScore` which is `undefined`.

The other problem is you aren't really handing the error case. If there is an error with the twitter client, you should respond to the request in a meaningful way, rather than just logging to the console. This way you can see, inside angular what the problem is instead of having to scratch your head and look at your server console:

```
if(!error) {
  //do normal stuff
}
else {
  res.status(500).send("Twitter error: " + error);
}
```

Same goes for `detectSentiment`:

```
document.detectSentiment(options, function(err, score) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      res.status(500).send("Error detecting sentiment: " +err);
    }
});
```

So, to fix your issue, you need to be responding inside your callbacks, not after:

```
router.post("/postUsername", function(req, res){
  ...
  client.get('statuses/user_timeline', {screen_name: req.body.userName, count:20}, function(error, tweets, response) {
    ...
    if (!error) {
      ...
      document.detectSentiment(options, function(err, score) {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
          res.status(500).send("Error detecting sentiment: " + err);
        } //if err
          ...
          console.log(finalScore);
          res.send(finalScore);
        });//detect sentiment
    }
    else {
      res.status(500).send("Twitter error: " + error);
    }
  });//client get statuses
});//router post
```

It seems a little weird, at first, that you have to nest your response so deep, but it's not at all. This is the world of javascript. There are ways to use promises and deferred objects to clean up your code, but for now it's best to write it like this so that it really sinks in how asynchronous code in javascript works.

Comment: What would be the best way to fix this?